# Problemas em exibir dados de uma tabela gerada automaticamente por causa da relação n para n, entity framework c#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Estou utilizando Entity Framework code first em C#, tenho as seguintes classes.

Procedimento (apenas o trecho relevante):

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
```

Produtos (apenas o trecho relevante):

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Procedimento> Procedimentos { get; set; }
```

A minha regra de negocio gera um n para n, com um pouco de pesquisa consegui ver que a melhor forma de resolver isso seria criando os atributos virtual `Icollection<>` em ambas as classes, meu banco foi gerado com sucesso porém em ambas as classes esse campo não aparece, no lugar foi gerada uma `tabelaprocedimentoproduto` que contem os campos(`IdProduto` e `IdProcedimento`), consigo salvar tranquilamente dentro dessa nova tabela, porém, não consigo recuperar os dados para trabalhar, o meu `context` não identifica esta nova tabela, já tentei usar o include porem não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Crie uma terceira classe, pode até ser esse nome ai, tabelaprocedimentoproduto, coloca as duas dentro dela, e depois mapeia com hasmany(procedimento).withmany(produto)

Comment: poderia ser um pouco mais claro na hora de mapear?